# Create column with first element of other column per month in R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have following dataset

```
ID    Date      NoEmployees
1     01-01-16  5
2     03-01-16  4
3     08-01-16  6
4     01-01-17  6
5     01-02-17  7
6     05-02-18  5 
7     06-02-18  4
8     01-03-18  3
9     01-04-18  4
```

I want to create an extra column that show per month the 'NoEmployees' at the start of this month, so when the first two characters of 'Date' are '01'. In this example there are 3 months represented: '01','02' and '03' which had values 5, 7 and 3 respecitively for 'NoEmployees'. So the output I want should look like below:

```
ID    Date      NoEmployees    NoEployeesAtStart
1     01-01-16  5              5 
2     03-01-16  4              5
3     08-01-16  6              5
4     01-01-19  6              6
4     01-02-17  7              7
5     05-02-18  5              7
6     06-02-18  4              7
7     01-03-18  3              3
8     01-04-18  4              4
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

**EDIT:**: The grouping should happen on the level of Month-year instead of only month.

Comment: Should rows 5 and 6 have the same year as row 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can extract the month after converting to `Date` class, group on it and get the `first` element

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      group_by(month = month(dmy(Date))) %>%
      mutate(NoEmployeesAtStart = first(NoEmployees)) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      select(-month)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, NoEmployeesAtStart := NoEmployees[1], .(month = month(dmy(Date)))]
```

Or as @lmo suggested, we can `as.IDate` instead of `dmy`

```
setDT(df1)[, NoEmployeesAtStart := NoEmployees[1], 
                .(month = month(as.IDate(Date, "%d-%m-%y")))]
```

Comment: Or purely with `data.table` (no `lubridate` functions): `setDT(dat)[, NoEmployeesAtStart := NoEmployees[1], .(month = month(as.IDate(Date, "%d-%m-%y")))]`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. However, I made an incorrect working example. It should by grouped based on mont/year, not only based on month. In the real dataset most dates occur multiple times over different years. I edit the question.

Comment: @user3387899  In that case, just replace with `.(month = month(dmy(Date)), year = year(dmy(Date)))]`

Answer (score 2):

With base R, you can use `ave` and indexing:

```
ave(dat$NoEmployees, cumsum(grepl("^01", dat$Date)), FUN=function(x) x[1])
[1] 5 5 5 7 7 7 3 4
```

Since the Date variable is not a Date object, I use `grepl` and `cumsum` for the grouping. You could also convert this vector to a Date (with `as.Date(dat$Date, "%d-%m-%y")`) and extract the day (with `format`), for the same result, but using the above method is more direct.